# How to handle multiple modals, one for every element in ngFor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

How do I make the data-target dynamic for a modal. I have a ngFor and need to specify a different modal for each element. I have tried,

data-target = "#{{element.id}}"

data-target = "# + element.id"

etc..

```
<div *ngFor="let element of elements">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="element.id">Label
    </button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="element.id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="element.name">

    etc...
```

Comment: You'd better use ng-bootstrap, and benefit from an angular-ish API to open modals (and more).

Comment: I feel like this will be my only option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a binding you need `[]` (or `{{}}`)

```
[attr.data-target]="element.id"

...

[attr.id]="element.id"
```

Comment: Unfortunatley [data-target] does not work, it is not a known property of 'button'

Comment: I did't suggest `[data-target]`. I suggested `[attr.data-target]`